# Http charset vs xml encoding (utf-8, utf-16, etc)

Tags: java, xml, http, encoding

Which one I should use to parse the xml file. what is the recommended approach to the parse http-xml file. my approach is read xml as String and use DocumentBuilder to parse the String.
Is this right approach.

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document doc = null;
        InputSource is = null;
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
        doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```

Comment: I would say one overwrites the other. If the http response specifies a given encoding then you initially set this for your parse/stream. If the xml has a <? xml ... encoding="..."> preamble I would hope the parser changes encoding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

XML specifies its own **encoding** in `<!xml encoding="...">` defaulting to UTF-8.
Using a StringReader using a String, already assumes that the reading has been done in a guessed encoding. *That seems less recommendable, than using a pure binary format, like File or InputStream.*

Another factor is the **document base**, to find included documents, xsd, dtd. There the usage of an **XML catalog** might help, storing such files offline.

Comment: but which encoding i should use. http or xml one ?

Comment: If you mean XHTML, HTML with the stricter XML conformant syntax, it still should be the XML encoding. **Both should be the same.** If you can manually call the URL in a browser, you can inspect and change the encoding.